# While generating an xml file in python, there are no spaces in output

Tags: python, xml

```
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

ET.SubElement(doc, "field1", name="blah").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "field2", name="asdfasd").text = "some vlaue2"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
print(ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True), file=open('test.xml', 'w'))
```

Hello, while trying to write an xml file in python with identation, I get just a one-line result. Though decoration has been set.

result:

```
b'<root>\n  <doc>\n    <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>\n    <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>\n  </doc>\n</root>\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is a byte string. You can convert it to a human readable string using the `decode` method. E.g:

```py
>>> s = b'<root>\n  <doc>\n    <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>\n    <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>\n  </doc>\n</root>\n'

>>> print(s.decode())
<root>
  <doc>
    <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>
    <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>
  </doc>
</root>
```

For more information about byte strings : [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

If your objective is to write this string to a file, you can do so like this :

```py
s = b'<root>\n  <doc>\n    <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>\n    <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>\n  </doc>\n</root>\n'

f = open("test.xml", "wb") # write bytes mode
f.write(s)
f.close()
```